# How are Nietzschean females evaluated for their genes?

Tags: andromeda

The Nietzschean people put a lot of emphasis in being genetically 'perfect' and enter marriages based on finding the best genes to have superior children.

In the show there are a few scenes that show and explain how males are always in competition and that even a game is a test to prove that you are superior.

I can't remember any similar scenes showing females competing. From what I remember they mostly watched the males, and then multiple wives would share the same husband.

Is there a similar cultural emphasis on women to compete to prove their perfections?

Comment: They like 'em big and muscular.

Answer (score 1):

**Female Nietzschean's most likely compete but not the same way and not for the same reasons as males but it is never really explored in the show.**

In the show we really never see a lot of Nietzschean females so I do not believe there is explicit canon, that being said.

Nietzschean society seems to be matriarchal at least when it comes to breeding and since males can have as many wives as they can attract it is doubtful that females have to prove their worthiness as a mate.

One episode had a barren female say that by proving herself in combat she would raise the status of her brothers.

The episode with the princess has her mention that her eggs have been removed and frozen to be implanted in lesser females, of course I am not sure how agreeing to a suicide mission actually proves your superiority.

Comment: Could you add in evidence from the episode, and what episode it is? It would strengthen your answer.

Comment: Also don't forget to register your account if you feel like sticking around!